# Ignoring onMouseMove in javascript debuggers

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, web-inspector

I'm trying to use the pause feature of the javascript debugger in Chrome.  The problem is that whenever I move the mouse over the page, the onMouseMove function is called and the script pauses at that point.  Is there any way to ignore this function so that the script pauses when I invoke the function I want to debug?

I have run into this problem several times, and it would be really helpful as it is sometimes not at all obvious what function I need to look at.  One part solution I have found is [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2), but this has it's limitations - last I checked it doesn't let you debug the functions, but it helps you work out what's going on.

I mentioned that I use chrome, but a solution in any browser or debugger would be good.

Comment: If you just need to debug certain parts of code, simply set a breakpoint there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem is when it is difficult to work out where the breakpoint should go, or if the JavaScript is loaded through ajax.

Comment: In the latter case you can use a `debugger;` statement in the code.

Comment: How are you invoking the function you want to debug, from the console or maybe by clicking an element on the page?

Comment: On the script tab there's a section called 'Event Listener Breakpoints'. You can use it to pause on specific type of event, for example on click, and ignore moveover/mousemove events.

Comment: Yeah, from clicking elements.  That 'Event Listener Breakpoints' is really useful, I'd used the DOM breakpoints, but hadn't noticed event listener.  That did the trick.

Comment: @Alexey You should submit that as an answer since that's what solved it for the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome debugger has a section called 'Event Listener Breakpoints' under 'Scripts' tab. It allows you to pause JavaScript execution on specific type of event, such as mouse click, and ignore all other types of events.

See [Chrome Developer Tools: Breakpoints](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-breakpoints.html), section 'Breakpoints on JavaScript Event Listeners'.

---

You can also see the list of all event listeners attached to a specific element. Open 'Event Listeners' section under 'Elements' tab.